Would Dividing circles in 2520 degrees instead of 360 degrees give extra advantage?
I have two questions
I am aware of the fact that historically babylonians used sexagecimal systems and it had mathematical advantage that the number $360^\circ$ has all divisors from $1$ to $10$ except $7$.
1)Does using $2520^\circ$ instead of $360^\circ$ give any other mathematical advantage?
2)What mathematical advantage does Radian system of Angles have over degree system?

Do you know calculus?  Because it matters for answering #2.

You have understood that the advantage of $360°$ : it has many divisors in particuliar angles 30°,45°,60°,90° that are used all the time, and it isn't a too sophisticated number. Taking a larger basis number, even if it has more divisor, is too complicated to manipulat for elementary tasks.

@peterwhy,It certainly does answer second part of my question

I've always thought that Plato's number was 5040, double your 2520 ;  evidently that was the first translator; later translators vary. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_number
